# How to modify/localize "This app does not have access to.." privacy message

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, plist

If I revoke the app's access permission to my photos, I get this, even if my device language isn't English:

[image]

Is there a way to localize this message?
I haven't found a suitable key to set in plist file.

Comment: is your app localized?

Comment: not yet. I've tried to set Localization native development key in plist both to en and it, with no results

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is localized automatically by the system. There's no way for you to localize it.

Your app has to have a localization for the language you want for the message to be shown in that language.

If your app has a French localization, and your system setting is French, the message will appear in French. But if your app isn't localized for French, the message appears in the base language for the app (usually English), despite the system language being set to French.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is os view and is dependent on ur device's selected language

Comment: it's not working like this, my device's selected language is Italian and the message is in English, as you can see